How to get my bitcoin out of Mycelium?
I want to leave Mycelium. I have heard nothing but that it’s Jurassic. I would like to use a new wallet. I have no idea what wallet to use but I have like $48 in bitcoins. I know it’s not a lot, but I just wanna move it out of there. Every time I try to send and receive, it is saying that I only have four dollars to spend when I have $48 to spend, so I don’t know why their fees are so high. I just wanna move my bitcoins. How can I do that?

When you build a transaction, is there a way to set your own feerate? Alternatively, could you check the wallet options to see if there is an option to turn on custom feerates? Then you could check on e.g. mempool.space for a feerate estimate and put in your own feerate estimation.
